# Best Practice - Sorting mixed objects in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of different NSManagedObjects in Swift. In Objective-C, it would have required just 2 lines of code (a sort descriptor and the actual sort). However, the only way I could figure out how to do it in swift required several lines of code. Is there a better and/or faster way than the code I wrote please?:

```
var orderMOs = [NSManagedObject]()
orderMOs.append(contentsOf: incidentMOs)
orderMOs.append(contentsOf: transferMOs)

orderMOs.sort (by: {(leftMO, rightMO) -> Bool in

   var leftDate: NSDate?
   var rightDate: NSDate?

   if leftMO is Incident {leftDate = (leftMO as! Incident).createdDate}
   else if leftMO is Transfer {leftDate = (leftMO as! Transfer).createdDate}

   if rightMO is Incident {rightDate = (rightMO as! Incident).createdDate}
   else if rightMO is Transfer {rightDate = (rightMO as! Transfer).createdDate}

   if leftDate == nil || rightDate == nil {return true}

   return leftDate!.compare(rightDate! as Date) == .orderedDescending
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use KVC here?

```
if let leftDate = leftMO.value(forKey: "createdDate") as? Date, 
   let rightDate = rightMO.value(forKey: "createdDate") as? Date {

    if leftDate == nil || rightDate == nil {return true}
    return leftDate.compare(rightDate) == . orderedDescending
}
```

Comment: this looks more like Objective-C than Swift. to make it more swifty you could use Swift 4 KeyPath syntax. Also using `compare` method is not needed anymore. `<` will do.

Comment: @vikingosegundo And how would using keyPath make this better? Then you must check what class leftMO & rightMO is first making the solution more like what OP already has. Using `<` is good suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

You should both your classes conform to a protocol that declares `createdDate`. Type `orderMOs` as such. than you won't need the conditional casts.

```
import Foundation

class A {

    init(created createdDate: Date) {
        self.createdDate = createdDate
    }
    let createdDate: Date
}


class B {
    init(created createdDate: Date) {
        self.createdDate = createdDate
    }
    var createdDate: Date
}

protocol Created {
    var createdDate: Date { get }
}


extension A: Created {}
extension B: Created {}

func createDate(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) -> Date {
    var comps = DateComponents()
    comps.year = year
    comps.month = month
    comps.day = day
    return Calendar.current.date(from: comps)!
}


var objects = [Created]()

objects.append(A(created: createDate(year: 2018, month: 2, day: 1)))
objects.append(B(created: createDate(year: 2017, month: 12, day: 1)))
objects.append(B(created: createDate(year: 2018, month: 5, day: 18)))
objects.append(A(created: Date()))
```

Sort it like

```
objects.sort { (c1, c2) -> Bool in
    return c1.createdDate < c2.createdDate
}
```

---

Another thing you can do is to use switch-statement with [pattern matching](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html) to clean code up a bit.